# Yii2 не работает ajax validation

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, валидация

Не могу разобраться с валидацией формы при отправке ajax.
У меня есть виджет с формой, во вьюхе которого находится ActiveForm.

```
//Это виджет формы

<?php
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

use app\models\AppForm;
use app\models\ApplicationDAO;

use Yii;

class ApplicationForm extends Widget{

    public function run(){

        $model = new AppForm();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
             $model->id = Yii::$app->user->id;// добавляем id 
             $applicationDAO = new ApplicationDAO();

        if($applicationDAO->create($model)) {
                return '1';
        } else { 
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
         }
       }
         return $this->render('apform');
    }

}
```

Это вьюха виджета (на деле полей больше)

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\MaskedInput;

?>

  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'create_application',
    //'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(['service/verify']),
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]); ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'phone') ?>
    <div class="form-group">
           <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'button_form']) ?>
    </div>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Если это важно, то код ajax:

```
$('#create_application').on('submit', function(event){  
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url : action,
        type: "POST",
        data : data,
        success: function(res) {
        },
        error: function (req, text, error) { 
           alert('Ошибочка! ' + text + ' : ' + error);
        },
    });
});
```

В БД все сохраняется идеально, но валидация формы не проходит. 
Если отправлять пустые данные, в консоли выводит ошибку, типо нельзя сохранять пустые данные в бд, ну он должен же сначала проверять на стороне клиента что форма пустая и нужно заполнить. Не работает в общем.
Буду благодарна любой помощи.

Comment: посмотрите js-код который сформировался на клиенте для формы(обычно бывает в нижней части body)

Comment: И приложите код AppForm и код метода контроллера на который отправляется форма. И вот этот код ajax не нужен Yii добавит его сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мда, я просто случайно подключила два файла jQuery, не думая о том, что в Yii2 он уже есть, и в итоге валидация никак не могла сработать.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите  проверять на стороне клиента, то сделайте проверку перед ajax запросом на jQuery или javascript

```html
('#create_application').on('submit', function(event){  
event.preventDefault();
var data = $(this).serialize();
var action = $(this).attr("action");

if ($('input[name=name]')){
alert('field name with error')
} 
else{

$.ajax({
...
)};

}

)};
```

если проверять на js не хотите то укажите в модели что если поле заполнено то ответ 1 иначе ошибка. Это для общего , что бы каждое поле не прописовать

Comment: В Yii2 же ajax берет правила валидации из модели формы. То есть автоматически, их не нужно прописывать в js, только в модели.

Comment: @Дарья все верно для этого вы используйте serialize() сам он ничего не берет и не делайт это делает разработчик, yii2 как любой фреймворк прсто выполняет